# How to access S3 on an AMI in the AWS Marketplace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-marketplace

I am in the process of creating an AMI for my application and putting it on the AWS Marketplace. My application requires access to an S3 bucket where the documents uploaded to my application are stored. When starting my application I request the user to input the Access key, secret key, and the bucket name like this:

```
docker run -d  --name ourcontainername -e UPLOAD_ACCESS=<access_key> -e UPLOAD_SECRET=<secret_key> -e UPLOAD_BUCKET=<bucket> ourimagename
```

However, it seems that AWS Marketplace does not allow this practice.

> However, for AWS Marketplace,we require application authors to use
>   AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles and do not permit the
>   use of access or secret keys.

I am reading this documentation that suggests ways to use IAM roles for this: https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-managing-access-to-aws-resources-in-aws-marketplace.pdf However, I can't make sense of how to do what they are suggesting. They suggest the following:

1. Create a new instance role.
2. Add a trust relationship that allows ec2.amazonaws.com to assume the
   role.
3. Create a new policy that specifies the permissions required.
4. Add the new policy to the new instance role.
5. Create a new EC2 instance that specifies the IAM role.
6. Build your app by using one of the AWS SDKs. Do not specify credentials
   when calling methods, because temporary credentials will be automatically
   added by the SDK.

Below I mention what I've done for each of the points above.

1. Done
2. I can not add a trust relationship. I pick the "Amazon EC2" service role and "Step 3: Establish Trust" is automatically filled for me

[image]

3 and 4. I attach the "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy

5. I started a new EC2 Instance that specifies the role created in (1)

However, I am not sure what (6) means?

> Build your app by using one of the AWS SDKs. Do not specify
>   credentials when calling methods, because temporary credentials will
>   be automatically added by the SDK.

On the new instance I created, when I do

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-42-131 ~]$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<rolename>
```

I can see the ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, and TOKEN. Should my application use these instead?

FWIW, my application is a Grails application that runs on JVM inside a docker container.

Comment: #6 means that your app should ideally access S3 (or whichever AWS resource needed) via an AWS SDK and the reason is so that your app doesn't have to worry about authentication. The SDK will leverage credentials that the EC2 instance has by nature of having been launched with an IAM role.

Comment: But as I have shown in the question, the ec2 instance launched with the IAM role does not have the metadata about the role. I have shown this in the curl command. Also, do you know if there is a sample that shows how to use the SDK to make the calls to S3 without access and secret key

Comment: iam/security-credentials/role-name

Comment: @jarmod can you please elaborate? is that the path to something? Thats what the URL I use on the ec2 instance for curl look like.

Comment: doh...I figured it out. It should be `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<role-name>` where `<role-name>` is the role name used in (1).