# Access key in EC2 instance does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

I've created a new IAM Role called "AMIRole" and I've attached "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy to it. Now I launch an EC2 instance with this IAM role.

When I am SSH'd into the instance I can get access to the AWS Access key and Secret key like this:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/AMIRole
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2016-12-21T16:05:26Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "ABCDEFJK",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "SECRET",
  "Token" : "TOKEN",
  "Expiration" : "2016-12-21T22:38:16Z"
}
```

However, when I try to create a bucket with this role, I get an error that this AWS KEY does not exist.

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.resource("s3", aws_access_key_id="ABCDEFJK", aws_secret_access_key="SECRET")
>>> s3.create_bucket(Bucket="something-specific-uuid")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 159, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 494, in _make_api_call
    raise ClientError(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the CreateBucket operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

My goal is to create an AMI that has rotating Access/secret keys so that I can put the AMI on AWS Marketplace.

Comment: I've edited your access key and secret key from the current version of the post because they're _still valid_ if they're correct credentials. For full safety, I'd recommend [invalidating the credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_revoke-sessions.html) (or deleting the role and recreating if it's not important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things about this:

1. It's the role attached to an instance that grants it specific resource policies and access to different things. The AMI does not matter in this regard. If you put your AMI onto the AWS Marketplace, users will not have access to the same role you're currently using.
2. The metadata service returns `AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey`, and `Token`. All three of those must be specified if you're trying to use those credentials, so you'll have to specify something like this for `boto3`:

   ```
   import boto3

   client = boto3.client(
       's3',
       aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
       aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
       aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
   )
   ```
3. When running code on the instance using an SDK like `boto3`, you don't need to provide the credentials at all. `boto3` will use the [IAM role's credentials from the metadata service](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) should it fail to find any other form of credentials

   > Note that if you've launched an EC2 instance with an IAM role configured, there's no explicit configuration you need to set in boto3 to use these credentials. Boto3 will automatically use IAM role credentials if it does not find credentials in any of the other places listed above.

   So for you, if you're running code directly on the instance using `boto3`, you could just create the `boto3.resource` without needing to specify access keys or secrets.

Comment: 3 - That is great information. thanks. 2 - I am unsure how this works then. My goal is to put my application on the AWS Marketplace. My application requires the users to put Accesskey, secret key, and a s3 bucket name. Since AWS doesn't allow this, I thought creating an AMI with an instance role will work. My other question provides bit more context for my end goal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169163/how-to-access-s3-on-an-ami-in-the-aws-marketplace

Comment: @Anthony I'll take a look at your other post and see if I can give guidance on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't be posting access keys and secret keys online.
2. You shouldn't be getting the access key and using it that way. Just use Boto3 (or any other AWS SDK, or the AWS CLI) without specifying any access/secret keys, and it will automatically use the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance it is running on.

Comment: 1 - I understand. I've changed them. 2 - I have to use the access keys that way because I plan to put the AMI on the marketplace. My other question might provide more context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169163/how-to-access-s3-on-an-ami-in-the-aws-marketplace

Comment: I believe the user would need to create the appropriate IAM role and select it when using your AMI. You might be able to provide a CloudFormation template that does this for the user of your AMI.